# How to print out who has the lowest and highest scores in a test?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, if-statement

**Code**

```
import re
from functools import reduce

def median(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n < 1:
        return None
    if n % 2 == 1:
            return sorted(lst)[n//2]
    else:
            return sum(sorted(lst)[n//2-1:n//2+1])/2.0

def main():
    file = open("grades.txt","r")
    i = file.readlines()
    num=[]
    for element in i:
        num.extend((re.findall('\d+',element)))
    results = list(map(int, num))
    print(results)
    print (reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, results) / len(results))
    print(median(results))

main()
```

**Text file:**

Gayle,Ujifusa,95

Bella,Luna,65

Bob,Jones,0

Alex,Fink,10

Nathan,Bono,0

Bob,Bono,0

Edith,Bono,0

Susie,Que,84

Arnold,George,80

Linda,Beth,100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important piece of Python knowledge, is knowing what already exists and then use it. There are built-in functions for finding minimum (`min`) and maximum (`max`) values. There is also built in statistical functions for finding mean and median values, found in the ´statisics` module. You should strive to use them.

To find multiple occurances of a min or max value, you may need to loop through your data a second time, though. Your code can be written as:

```
import re
from statistics import median, mean

# Read in results into a dict, to allow further manipulation:
persons = {}
with open('grades.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match('(.*),(.*),(.*)', line)
        if m:
            person = '{} {}'.format(m[1], m[2])
            grade = int(m[3])
            persons[person] = grade

# Find min and max grade value
# Only look for the value since the dict needs to be iterated to find
# multiple occurances anyway.
min_grade = min(persons.values())
max_grade = max(persons.values())

# Loop dict to find all persons with min/max grades
lowest = []
highest = []
for person, grade in persons.items():
    if grade == min_grade:
        lowest.append(person)
    if grade == max_grade:
        highest.append(person)

# Gather and print statistics
print('Stats:')
print('Min grade {}: {} ({})'.format(
        min_grade, ', '.join(lowest), len(lowest)))
print('Max grade {}: {} ({})'.format(
        max_grade, ', '.join(highest), len(highest)))
print('Median: {}'.format(median(persons.values())))
print('Mean: {}'.format(mean(persons.values())))

# Print all students and their grades, somewhat formatted
print('\nGrade list:')
for person, grade in persons.items():
    print('{:14} {:3}'.format(person, grade))
```

This is quite different from your code. It does have a number of nice Python constructs that you should try to learn and use, though, such as the `with` construction and reading a file line-by-line. It also uses the very nice `dict` data type. Also, it avoids `reduce` since there are many that thinks that makes the code harder to read (even though I, personally, like it).